# How to "git reset --soft HEAD^" a single file?

Tags: git

When I am splitting a commit during interactive rebase, I often would like to extract specific files from the last commit.

My current process is to

1. Copy the last commit message to my clipboard,
2. git reset --soft HEAD^ (last commit is undone, changes are staged)
3. Unstage files I wanted extract
4. Re-commit (pasting in the copied commit message)
5. Add/commit the remaining files
6. Continue with rebase

I feel like this would be simpler if I could soft reset a specific file.

Answer (score 13):

Are you trying to do `git checkout $COMMIT_HASH some_file.ext`?

You can use this to revert a file to its previous state, **and git stages this change.**

Comment: This in combination with `git commit --amend` would get me halfway there, except the change itself is lost.


In short, I want to split changes out of the previous commit without having to reset the whole commit.

Comment: No, checking out a single file does not wipe out your other changes. It just reverts that one file.

Comment: The only apparent problem (?) is that `git checkout` touches the work tree while `git reset $commit -- $path` does not.

Answer (score 10):

It seems this does what you want :

> **`git reset [-q] [commit] [--] paths…`** This form resets the index
>   entries for all `paths` to their state at `commit`. (It does not
>   affect the working tree, nor the current branch.)
>
> This means that git reset  is the opposite of git add .

Comment: One should add that this (`git reset -- path`) step is to be done after the `git reset --soft HEAD^`.  The idea here is to step `HEAD` back one commit without changing *anything* in the index or work-tree, then to make one change to the index (but not the work tree) using the new, stepped-back `HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's an optimal solution.

```
git reset HEAD~
git add .
git commit
(optional) git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way could be

1. Add all files

   git add .
2. Now reset the files you do not want to commit

   git reset 'file1.ext'
   git reset 'file2.ext'
   ...
   so on
3. Continue your commit and push